# Detect if Cron is Running

Tags: wp-cron, cron

Many times I have code and I want to make sure it only runs in a cron context, or it never runs in a cron context.

Is there an `is_cron_running` style function?

Comment: I'm a bit fed up of constantly googling for the answer to this then forgetting it, and the SEO on stack exchange is pretty good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `wp_doing_cron` will return true if the current request is a WP Cron request, or if it's triggered from WP CLI

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_cron/